# Create New Table From Other Table After Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, insert

How can I insert to a table a value from "grouping" other table?
That means I have 2 table with different structure.

The table ORDRE with existed DATA

Table ORDRE:

```
ORDRE ID  |  CODE_DEST | 
-------------------------
    1     |     a      |    
    2     |     b      |    
    3     |     c      |    
    4     |     a      |    
    5     |     a      |    
    6     |     b      |    
    7     |     g      |
```

I want to INSERT the value FROM Table ORDRE INTO TABLE VOIT:

```
 ID_VOIT  |  ORDRE ID  |    CODE_DEST | 
 ---------------------------------------
    1     |     1      |         a    |   
    1     |     4      |         a    |    
    1     |     5      |         a    |   
    2     |     2      |         b    |     
    2     |     6      |         b    |    
    3     |     3      |         c    |     
    4     |     7      |         g    |
```

Comment: Need a little more to help you out here.  You don't really give a clue as to how to transform your starting table into your expected result.  Where does ID_VOIT come from?

Comment: you want to create new table or insert into existing one ? and is the IT_VOIT mandatory?

Comment: i have 2 table...sory not good explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my best guess on what you need using only the info available.

```
declare @Ordre table
(
  ordre_id int,
  code_dest char(1)
)
declare @Voit table
(
  id_voit int,
  ordre_id int,
  code_dest char(1)
)

insert into @Ordre values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'a'),
(5,'a'),
(6,'b'),
(7,'g')


insert into @Voit
select id_voit, ordre_id, rsOrdre.code_dest
from @Ordre rsOrdre
inner join
(
  select code_dest, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by code_dest) as id_voit
  from @Ordre
  group by code_dest
) rsVoit on rsVoit.code_dest = rsOrdre.code_dest
order by id_voit, ordre_id


select * from @Voit
```

[Working Example.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119445/)

Comment: +1 for ROW_NUMBER over... wish I had thought of that instead of a massive case statement.  That being said, I still think there are some benefits of moving that association into it's own table.  THAT being said, I really have no idea if there are or not because I don't fully understand what OP is attempting to accomplish.  :)

Comment: @JeremyWiggins Agreed.  Best guess based on available info.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific data you give as an example, this works:

```
insert into VOIT
select 
case code_dest
 when 'a' then 1
 when 'b' then 2
 when 'c' then 3
 when 'g' then 4
 else 0
end, orderId, code_dest from ORDRE order by code_dest, orderId
```

But it kind of sucks because it requires hard-coding in a huge case statement.

Test is here - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119442/

What I like more is moving the VOIT ID / Code_Dest associations to a new table, so then you could do an `inner join` instead.

```
insert into VOIT
select voit_id, orderId, t.code_dest 
from ORDRE t
join Voit_CodeDest t2 on t.code_dest = t2.code_dest
order by code_dest, orderId
```

Working example of that here - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119443/